# Using multiple NICs on Packet Tracer

Tags: ip

Using Packet Tracer, can I connect a server with two NICs, one to a router, the other to a LAN:

```
my router int 192.168.0.1 / 24
my server fa0/0 192.168.0.2  255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
my server fa0/1 192.168.1.2  255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
my pc 192.168.1.5 255.255.255.0.192.168.1.1 **********
```

Is this possible?

I am getting this :

```
Router(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/0
Router(config-if)#ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
Router(config-if)#no shutdown

SERVER>ipconfig

FastEthernet0 Connection:(default port)

   Link-local IPv6 Address.........: FE80::210:11FF:FE67:6BDC
   IP Address......................: 192.168.0.2
   Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway.................: 192.168.0.1

FastEthernet1 Connection:

   Link-local IPv6 Address.........: FE80::201:C9FF:FE22:4A5A
   IP Address......................: 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway.................: 192.168.1.1

    SERVER>ping 192.168.0.1

    Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:

    Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=0ms TTL=255
    Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=0ms TTL=255
    Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=0ms TTL=255
    Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=0ms TTL=255

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

SERVER>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

astEthernet0 Connection:(default port)

   Link-local IPv6 Address.........: FE80::2D0:58FF:FE2B:28C4
   IP Address......................: 192.168.1.5
   Subnet Mask.....................: 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway.................: 192.168.1.1

PC>ping 192.168.1.1

Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

PC>ping 192.168.0.1

Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Dear sir my stats

Comment: You asked if it was possible to add a second NIC on a server in packet tracer, which was answered. Troubleshooting your configuration is a separate issue which need a separate question - with more details (network diagram, full devices configuration and interfaces status)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it is possible.
In packet tracer 7.0 for example:

- add a generic server
- shutdown it (1)
- add a second NIC (2 & 3)
- power on the server (4)
- go to the config tab (5)
- set the IP for both NIC
- connect the NIC to your router and switch

Note: by default the server has a FastEternetInterface and in this example I added a second one; but you could remove the existing interface and put two gigabit interfaces (module PT-HOST-NM-1CGE)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I add more than 2 NICs on the same server? Thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: @Roman, PacketTracer is aimed at Cisco CCNA course, in which it is not needed to have multihomed server. Don't expect too much from PacketTracer.